# python matplotlib : plot vertical_barplotcolor with classes

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart

I'm currently looking for a tips or two to make vertical parallel barplot (or rectangles) with different colours according to the data.
For example, the plot of this `data = [1,1,1,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]` would be something like:

[image]

Comment: Out of interest. How did you produce the plot/image you're showing?

Comment: With paint for this example of 16 values. I have to produce this kind of picture of 8 x 5000 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is easily done with matplotlib. The following code exactly produces the result from above

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [1,1,1,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
col= [None, '#1620c0', '#e11239', '#2f9007' ]
colors = [col[d] for d in data]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
# create bar plot 
#       postions of bars   , all 1 in height   , all 1 in width    , color according to data, no line
ax.bar(np.arange(len(data)), np.ones(len(data)), np.ones(len(data)), color=colors, linewidth=0 )
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

#### Update:

In case you need a picture of 8 x 5000 pixels, you need to make sure to save it with the according resolution. The following code produces a png image of dimensions 8 x 5000.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(1,4, 5000)
col= [None, '#1620c0', '#e11239', '#2f9007' ]
colors = [col[d] for d in data]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,8./1000))
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.bar(np.arange(len(data)), np.ones(len(data)), np.ones(len(data)), color=colors, linewidth=0 )
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("SO_coloredbars.png", dpi=1000)
```